# Subject and text not appearing when trying to share image via chooser

Tags: android

I am converting a view to a bitmap and sharing it via the Intent.createChooser :

```
fun share(charityName: String, url: String) {

    val builder = VmPolicy.Builder()
    StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build())

    val bitmap = logoHolder.drawToBitmap()

    var path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString() + "/share.jpeg"
    var out: OutputStream? = null
    val file = File(path)
    try {
        out = FileOutputStream(file)
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out)
        out.flush()
        out.close()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    path = file.path
    val bmpUri = Uri.parse("file://$path")
    val shareIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)


    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, resources.getString(R.string.invite_subject))
    shareIntent.putExtra(
        Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
        resources.getString(R.string.inviteWithUrl, charityName, url)
    )
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmpUri)

    shareIntent.type = "image/jpeg"
    shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)



    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share"))
}
```

The sharing functionality works, but the only text that appears in the chooser is the file name (share.jpeg)

Is there a way to have the chooser contain all relevant information?

Comment: `and sharing it via the chooser intent:` ???? Via ACTION_SEND you mean.

Comment: Sure, via ACTION_SEND intent